# Import csv file, calculate average according to the first header and create graph

Tags: python, csv, graph, average

I have a list in csv format with this style:

Line,ALTURA
L10015,95.95
L10015,98.2
L10015,99.17
L10015,98.17
L10015,95.76
...
L10025,109.44
L10025,116.87
L10025,127.57
...
L10035,111.52
...

I would like to import this csv list on Python 3.x (I am using Spyder) and calculate the average of ALTURA for each type of line (whenever the name of the line changes). For example, the average for L10015, then the average for L10025, for L10035 and so on.

This file has 1,759,679 rows (including the headers) and I think Excel is not the best software to work with this data.

I would like to create also a graph with the average value for each line (axis y) versus line (axis x).

I did:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\..\Downloads\teste_gama.csv')
mean1 = df['ALTURA'].mean()
print ('Total arithmetic mean: ' + str(mean1))
groupby_mean1 = df.groupby(['Line']).mean()
print('Mean of values, grouped by Line: ' + str(groupby_mean1))

df.groupby("Line")['ALTURA'].mean().plot(kind='bar')
```

I think I manage to have the mean values by each line. However, how can I fix my plot to show the x labels in a vertical orientation and to be more spaced? Is there a way to add a horizontal constant line in the value 100?
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhBzP.png)

Comment: So what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I’ll second what @jonrsharpe said. Stack Overflow is not a place where people do all your work for you.

Comment: Nice way to motivate non-programming users to find help in the stack community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a first hint, I would suggest that you use the pandas package to load your csv.
It will create a dataframe. The using the function `group by` you can compute the average over each group.
Have a look here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html

To create the graph, once you have computed the mean, you can use the `plot` function of pandas https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html

Comment: Thank you, Thombou. I just know some basics of programming and checking the pandas documentation really helped me.